# Why I can't assign struct returned by a function to struct?

Tags: c, stm32, c11, cortex-m, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I wrote "lightweight" time library and I have struct and typedef like this:

```
struct tmt {
    uint16_t year;
    uint8_t month;
    uint8_t day;
    uint8_t hour;
    uint8_t minute;
    uint8_t second;
    uint8_t weekday;
    uint8_t is_dst; 
};

typedef struct tmt tm_t;
```

I have a function that returns `tm_t`:

```
tm_t rtc_get_current_time(void){
    tm_t tm;
    xSemaphoreTake(rtc_mutex, RTC_MUTEX_MAX_WAIT);
    tm = rtc.current_time;
    xSemaphoreGive(rtc_mutex);
    return tm;
}
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
tm_t s;
s = rtc_get_current_time();    // error is here
```

I'm getting this error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'tm_t' {aka 'struct tmt'} from type 'int'

---

I have also tried to change function and variable like this:

```
struct tmt rtc_get_current_time(void){
    tm_t tm;
    xSemaphoreTake(rtc_mutex, RTC_MUTEX_MAX_WAIT);
    tm = rtc.current_time;
    xSemaphoreGive(rtc_mutex);
    return tm;
}

struct tmt tm = rtc_get_current_time();
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Kamil What is the type of rtc.current_time?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is `tm_t`, but the error is not at this line. It is at `s = rtc_get_current_time();`. Sorry for not pointing that.

Comment: The root of your problems seems to be that you are using an outdated compiler or running it in "outdated mode". See [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is complaining that you are trying to assign an `int` to a `tm_t`, but since you implemented `rtc_get_current_time()` as returning a `tm_t`, this implies that the compiler thinks `rtc_get_current_time()` is returning an `int` instead of a `tm_t`.

That can happen if `rtc_get_current_time()` has not been *declared* yet in the context where it is being called.  The C language allows a function to be called without a prior declaration, but then you end up with the compiler assuming a default declaration for the function, and that default uses `int` as the return type. You don't want that in this case.

You need to declare `rtc_get_current_time()` before you call it.

Comment: Oh dear... I missed include. I didn't expected such compiler behavior. I have to read some books.

Comment: Re “The C language allows a function to be called without a prior declaration…“: Implicit function declarations were removed from the C standard in the 2011 version. An undeclared identifier is a violation of the language syntax (C 2018 note 94), so a conforming declaration must diagnose it.